# Efficient way to create CSV files from marklogic db

Tags: marklogic

I want to convert my json documents in marklogic db to CSV file(i.e.comma limited).My data looks like this

Sample Data :

```
{
"One": {
"Name": "One",
"Country": "US"
}, 
"Two": {
"State": "kentucky"
}, 
"Three": {
"Element1": "value1", 
"Element2": "value2", 
"Element3": "value3", 
"Element4": "value4"
}
}
```

My database has 1.5 Millions of documents . I didn't find any option in mlcp export for converting into csv file. Went through other tools like `java client api(i.e.DMSDK)` and `CORB` .

1. Wanted to know whether using these tools can i achieve my goal and
   which is better in both of them ?
2. Is there any thirty party tools for achieving this ?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this, I would suggest [Corb2](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2)

This simple Hello World example ends up with a csv file as output and is a good base to build from: [Hello World Example](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/wiki/Hello-World-from-CORB)

Having said that, It is well worth the time to go through the [wiki](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/wiki) and understand the concepts of Corb. There are different ways to handle modules and configuration and the Hello World makes certain choices in its implementation. Having the background info will make extending the example easier.